# Codeigniter "Call to undefined function mysqli_init()" error

Tags: codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I am receiving this error in CodeIgniter app on localhost

Here are the error lines:

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Error

Message: Call to undefined function mysqli_init()

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\domainswat.com\system\database\drivers\mysqli\mysqli_driver.php

Line Number: 135

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\domainswat.com\application\controllers\Login.php
Line: 17
Function: __construct

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\domainswat.com\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

I have already changed the "mysql" to "mysqli" in my code but error persists.

When trying to access phpMyAdmin, it says that mysqli extension is missing but it is not missing.

I also checked the config file and it refers to that DLL file.

So I am out of ideas here...
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

edit yours php config `php.ini`
search for mysqli and delete semicolon `;` it look likes this

```
;extension=php_ldap.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll  
extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_oci8_12c.dll  
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Comment: Thanks but these ext are already enabled.